# Command Execution Error while executing ecr login command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I am getting error in PRE_BUILD section of Code Pipeline while deploying ECS. While executing commmand for ecr login, i am getting exit status with error code 255. please see below image.

Command : `- $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Build Service Role automatically created in Code Pipeline was unable to access ECR, thats why i was getting `exit status 255`.

Solved the issue by atttaching policy `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser` to Codebuild role created.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got `aws` *and* `docker` commands available in the environment?

Insert a line `- set -x` just *above* the `ecr get-login` line - hopefully it will display the actual commands executed.

Comment: Thanks @122588 i already solved the issue, i will post the answer. Issue occur because code deploy role permission issue.